# How does `build` occur from root to leaves in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I've tried tracing through the source to answer this but I get a little lost in the Flutter machinery. We pass `runApp` a Widget, which becomes the root widget of our app. That widget must implement `build`, which returns a Widget.

Does Flutter just use simple recursion to call `build` on that returned Widget, and so on, for the Widget returned by each subsequent child's `build` method?

While recursing, and it encounters a StatelessWidget, does Flutter do a type check to call `createState` instead of `build`, and then perform an extra step, calling `build` on the State that `createState` returns?

How does the recursive / chain of calls to `build` methods stop? For example, the Text widget has a `build` method that returns a RichText widget, which is a MultiChildRenderObjectWidget. Does Flutter again do type checking here and stop calling `build` and instead invoke `createElement`, which in the end generates the elements for the Element tree?

Answer (score 2):

It is more complex than a simple recursion.

You can read more about the build and render process of a widget here
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBinding/drawFrame.html

While the widgets are inmutable, [`Elements`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Element-class.html) are the instantiation of them. So while `StatelessWidget`s and `StatefulWidget`s are recreated in each build, `Element`s are updated in the tree.

The `StatefulWidget` is managed by `StatefulElement` that keeps the state instance in its instance, so it persits while the StatefulWidget is rebuilt

The docs has a very good explanation of what is an `Element` too: 
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Element-class.html